# Question about inverse Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I have here a probably a very easy inverse Laplace transform.

I just can not figure out why $$ L^{-1}( \frac{1}{s^2} \frac{s-a}{s+a}) =-t + \frac2a- \frac2a e^{-at} $$

Is there a conversion I don't see?
I appreciate any help with !

Comment: What is the Laplace transform of $(-t + \frac2a- \frac2a e^{-at})1_{t > 0}$ ? And for the inverse Laplace transform we need to specify a domain of convergence (here $\Re(s) > \max(0,-\Re(a))$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(s)= \frac{1}{s^2} \frac{s-a}{s+a} $$
$$f(s)= \dfrac 1 s  \left(\dfrac{1}{s} \dfrac{s-a}{s+a} \right) $$
$$f(s)= \dfrac 1 s  \left(\dfrac{A}{s}+ \dfrac{B}{s+a} \right) $$
$$f(s)= \dfrac 1 s \left ( \dfrac{(A+B)s+Aa}{s(s+a)}\right) $$
Where $A+B=1$ and $A=-1  \implies B=2$ so that we have:
$$f(s)= \dfrac 1 s \left(-\dfrac{1}{s}+ \dfrac{2}{s+a}\right) $$
$$f(s)= -\dfrac{1}{s^2}+ \dfrac{2}{s(s+a)} $$
$$f(s)= -\dfrac{1}{s^2}+ \dfrac 2 a \left(\dfrac{1}{s}-\dfrac {1}{s+a} \right) $$
Apply inverse Laplace transform now.
$$f(t)= -t+ \dfrac 2 a \left(1-e^{-at} \right) $$